# Raspbian: Reset Bash environment variables

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, cron, raspbian

I was trying to get a crontab working on my Raspberry PI and I think I messed up my environment variables. I can execute a file from the GUI by right-clicking and choosing execute. However I cannot get the same file to run from command line. I can use `ls` to see the file (ChromeTab.sh), but when I type `ChromeTab.sh`, I get **"bash: ChromeTab.sh: command not found"**.

I think I messed up my environment variables when I put this in the crontab.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

I followed the examples in [Script doesn't run via `crontab` but works fine standalone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117978/script-doesnt-run-via-crontab-but-works-fine-standalone).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** 
OK,
Let me clarify what efforts I took on my part BEFORE posting my question on stackoverflow before getting anymore downvotes.

First of all thanks S. Adam Nissley for your suggestions.
In answer to your steps listed above.
Running this from home path, or fully qualified path does Not work as stated. 
Error: bash: ChromeTab.sh: command not found

```
./ChromeTab.sh
```

I have also ensured read/write and execute permissions on the file with

```
chmod +x ./ChromeTab.sh
```

Also, my bash script starts off with the following shebang

```
#!/bin/sh
```

So, what i'm trying to say is, regardless of using crontab or not the issue at hand is that I can not even execute the script from command line. This started happening after I was messing around with the environment variables in the crontab. I'm looking for a way to revert to the situation where I can at least run/execute bash commands from the terminal.

The only way I can effectively execute this script is (right-click execute) through the GUI.

Comment: Your `PATH` looks very normal. Current working directory `.` should *not* be in your `PATH` (as you wish here, if I correctly interpreted your question) or you'll run into serious security risks. What you should do is to specify the full path to `CrhomeTab.sh` in the crontab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are in the same directory as your script, you should just be able to enter

```
./ChromeTab.sh
```

If it does not execute, make sure it is executable with the command

```
chmod +x ./ChromeTab.sh
```

Or

```
chmod 755 ./ChromeTab.sh
```

And if it still won't execute, make sure it has an appropriate hashbang on the very first line of the script like `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`

---

When you add it to your crontab, make sure it has the full path like

```
/home/pi/bin/ChromeTab.sh  <br/>
```

---

**EDIT: Default PATH and SHELL for Raspbian**  
You can *check* your PATH and SHELL environmental variables from the command line as follows:

```
echo $SHELL
echo $PATH
```

The default PATH for *Rasbian* is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

And the default SHELL is:

```
/bin/bash
```

So if you need to set those it is as simple as:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

---

If you are having other issues with your environment, you may want to disable some of your local settings to see if the problem is in your profile. You can list all files with `ls -a`, which includes hidden files. *Raspbian* typically has a `.bashrc` and a `.profile` in each user's home directory. To disable them simple rename them:

```
mv .bashrc .bashrc_disabled
mv .profile .profile_disabled
```

If that solves the problem, you can inspect the files and make the necessary corrections before renaming them back to their original names.

Comment: OK,
Let me clarify what efforts I took on my part BEFORE posting my question on stackoverflow.

In answer to your steps listed above.

Comment: @NetFlash I put up some info regarding Raspbian defaults.

Comment: @Adamn, 
OK I've tried all of the above except renaming .profile and .bashrc. How do you troubleshoot by disabling them? Another thing, i've checked the /bin folder. bash is there and so is dash, however the sh is a shortcut to dash instead of bash. Is this correct?

Comment: @NetFlash Yes sh is a symlink to dash  `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Dec 31  1969 sh -> dash`

Comment: @NetFlash If you disable the files (*and then open a new terminal*) and things are working then you know that there is a problem with one of them. If that is the case, you can identify the problem and then name them back. There is a copy of `.bashrc` at https://github.com/rosterloh/raspberry-pi/blob/master/configs/.bashrc

Comment: @Adam, thanks.
After fooling around a bit, I can note the following. 
Running the $ ChromeT.sh file still gives the error "Bash command not found", however running $ bash ChromeT.sh does work. I've double checked the SHELL and PATH and they coincide with what you've written above. Anything else I can try?

Comment: What is the *very* first line in the ChromeT.sh file?

Comment: #!/bin/sh

I also tried with #!/bin/bash. But both produce the same error.
bash: ChromeT.sh: command not found

Comment: Please change it back to `#!/bin/bash`. Please confirm that you are in the directory containing the file. Confirm that when you run `ls -lh ChromeT.sh` the file has "x" in the 4th, 7th, and 10th positions. Confirm that at the prompt you are entering exactly `./ChromeT.sh`

Comment: Got it. 
I took the new .bashrc from github AND restarted the Pi, now it is working again. Many thanks @Adam for the help in troubleshooting, appreciate it, you rock !!